# Having trouble solving ode in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab and want to solve the ode's

```
x'(t) = a - bx(t) + x(t)^2 * y(t) - x(t)
y'(t) = bx(t) - x(t)^2 * y(t)
```

where I know x(0) = y(0) = 0.9, and a = 1, b= 1.9;

Ideally I want to end up plotting the solution.
I looked online but am having trouble figuring out how to do it. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Start off using `ode45`, read through the Matlab documentation and examples, if you are still struggling, search on StackOverflow for `ode45` problems.

Answer (score 0):

Main Program:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

ts = 0;
te = 100;
dt_ode = 0.025;

t_ode = ts : dt_ode : te;

a = 1.0;
b = 1.9;
x0 = 0.9; % x(0)
y0 = 0.9; % y(0)

options=[];
[t_ode, res_ode] = ode45(@user_fun, t_ode, [x0 y0], options, a, b);

% Plot:
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t_ode, res_ode(:,1)); 
xlabel('t');
ylabel('x');
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t_ode, res_ode(:,2)); 
xlabel('t');
ylabel('y');
```

Create a file named user_fun.m:

```
function zdot = user_fun(t,z,a,b)
% x == z(1)
% y == z(2)

zdot(1) = a - b*z(1) + (z(1)^2)*z(2) - z(1);
zdot(2) = b*z(1) - (z(1)^2)*z(2);

zdot=zdot'; % transpose
```

This files defines your system of differential equations. I used z to rename the x and y.